# Реализации включения файлов в php

Tags: php, файлы, исключения, include

Гуляя по интернету и своей голове, выбрал для себя 3 толковых способа включения файлов.

---

Первый:

```
if(!(@include_once 'file.php'))
    throw new MyException('file not found');
```

---

Второй:

```
if(!file_exists('file.php'))
    throw new MyException('file not found');
include_once 'file.php';
```

---

Третий:

```
set_error_handler(function() {
    // Работа над ошибками
    throw new MyException('file not found');
    return true;
});
// ........
include_once 'file.php';
```

---

Насколько я вычитал, первый способ будет в разы медленнее второго.
Третий способ выглядит намного "красивше" остальных, но нужно как-то определять, что ошибка именно с включением файла и не обрабатывать остальные так же.
Второй просто не элегантный и хочется использовать третий, но не знаю, как преодолеть проблему, описанную выше.

Answer (score 0):

Если пишите на фреймворке, то `set_error_handler` там обычно по дефолту уже установлен, не надо его переписывать.

Если пишите сами, то одним-же инклудом у вас дело не закончится? Реализуйте какой-нить общий класс или функцию, например `my_include()`, и в ней реализуйте второй способ, и потом просто вызывайте `my_include('my_file');` (будут проблемы с видимостью, но надеюсь у вас инклуды - это назависимые файлы, иначе придется обернуть все это дело в контейнер).

По поводу проблемы, вам-же не обязательно выкидывать `Exception` в `my_include`. Делаем класс `logs`, и при ошибках обращаемся к нему, а он в свою очередь может вызывать ваш `Exception` с нужным Вам текстом.

P.S. В дальнейшем вы можете такую систему развить и привинчивать ко всему что только есть, там вы получите полный контроль над своим проектом, потом на проде можно будет в классе `logs` добавить запись в файл, и теперь мы будем знать кто, когда, где и какой получал эксепшн.

Comment: Ясно, примерно придумал, как это сделать. Единственное, не пойму, в какой контейнер надо обернуть инклуды, чтобы не назваться проблем с областью видимости.

Comment: @AlexChashin Просто обычно не инклудят кусок кода, обычно инклудят либо класс, и у него проблем нет(ибо он в контейнере и все доступно), либо функцию всю целиком. Вот вы и по чуть чуть сталкиваетесь с архитектурой :)

Comment: Ну с классами и кусками кода другими проблем не возникнет) Там если что можно внутри устанавливать переменные в глобальные по умолчанию. Просто мне ещё немного сложно разобраться с тем, как воткнутся куски html. Если я делаю свой класс для инклудов и реализую все это дело с помощью метода __invoke, воткнутся ли это куда мне надо

Comment: @AlexChashin всмысле куски `html`? В классах не должно быть `html`, для них своя отдельная папочка, если не знаете можете погуглить `MVC`

Comment: Не в классах конечно, просто файлы отдельные с html, макет сайта, его же тоже надо везде включать. Плюс пара блоков, которые включаются в зависимости от состояния